# Add woocommerce variation images in gallery?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

WooCoommerce doesn't show variation images within gallery on product pages( thumbnails below main product image ). This said, is there an plugin, preferably free, that allows this functionality? Ie. add an image for each variation and have those images shown as thumbnails below main product image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugin name:(Additional Variation Images Gallery for WooCommerce)

Allows to insert multiple images for per variation to let visitors to see a different images when WooCommerce product variations are switched.

Comment: tried it, but that doesn't work. I don't need multiple images per variation, only one.